# How correctly to rewrite this class on TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Help me to rewrite this class in TypeScript and help me understand why it does not work

```js
class Students {
    public name: string;
    public surname: string;
    public age: number;
}
constructor(name:string,surname:string,age:number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}
public refactorStudent(name:string, surname:string,age:number):void {
    this.name = typeof name !== 'undefined' ? name : this.name;
this.surname = typeof surname !== 'undefined' ? surname : this.surname;
this.age = typeof age !== 'undefined' ? age : this.age;
}
public toString():object{} {
    return `\nName: ${this.name}, Surname: ${this.surname} Age: ${this.age}`
}
let student1 = new Students("Aladin","Indus", 20);
console.log(student1.toString());
```

Comment: Your toString() method should return a string and not an object{}.
Please show us the error you have so we can help better

Answer (score 1):

I think based on the information provided this is what you are looking for?

```
export class Students {

    public name: string;
    public surname: string;
    public age: number;

    constructor(name: string, surname: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;

        let student1 = new Students("Aladin", "Indus", 20);
        console.log(student1.toString());
    }

    public refactorStudent(name: string, surname: string, age: number): void {

        this.name = typeof name !== 'undefined' ? name : this.name;
        this.surname = typeof surname !== 'undefined' ? surname : this.surname;
        this.age = typeof age !== 'undefined' ? age : this.age;
    }

    public toString(): string {
        return `\nName: ${this.name}, Surname: ${this.surname} Age: ${this.age}`;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The public fields can be initialised automatically in the constructor.
Almost certainly `refactorStudent` would be better done by just assigning to the `public` attributes. If you need to protect those assignments in future you can define `get` and `set` methods for the attributes but only when needed.

```
export class Students {
    constructor(public name: string, public surname: string, public age: number) {}

    public toString(): string {
        return `\nName: ${this.name}, Surname: ${this.surname} Age: ${this.age}`;
    }
}

let student1 = new Students("Aladin", "Indus", 20);
console.log(student1.toString());
```

The main reason your original code would not work was that the constructor and methods have to be inside the class definition but you had defined them outside the class.

Also the class itself should be called `Student` as an instance represents a single student. Use singular for class names unless the class represents a collection of the objects. So a class `Students` would be appropriate if it contained several students (e.g. a classroom full of them) rather than a single student.